# JQuery checkbox state is updated differently between group click() and $.each(obj.click())

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox

The code below doesn't work in the same behavior. The sequence of click event and calling foo() is different. I want to know why they behave different sequence between call click() and iterate the objects before call click() on each.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      function foo(obj){
        alert(obj.id+" ->"+obj.checked);
      }

      function clickAll(val){
        if (val) {
          $(":checkbox").click();
        } else {
          $(":checkbox").each(function(i,obj){
              obj.click();
              });
        }
      }
    </script> 
  </head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" onclick="foo(this)" /> a
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" onclick="foo(this)" /> b
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" onclick="foo(this)" /> c
<input type="button" onclick="clickAll(true)" value="click all" />
<input type="button" onclick="clickAll(false)" value="click all each" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of…

```
$(":checkbox").each(function(i,obj){
 obj.click();
});
```

Try:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
 $(this).click();
});
```

Comment: Oh! thanks! click() of standard HTML DOM and JQuery method. T-T

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":checkbox").each(function(i,obj){ // i is an index and obj is a dom element object... 
    //obj.click();  not a jQuery Object that is why it's not working as expected
    $(obj).click(); // do this instead..
});
```